# noob selenium xpath from cell in row

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the data out of a table. I have the table and can iterate the rows.

I loop through the rows and am trying to find cells by unique heading value. Each column has a unique header:

`<TD headers=colSequence>`

so I want code that will

```
string strSequence = allRows[z].FindElement(By.XPath(.... something...)).Text;
```

Where the search starts at the current row.

```
string strSequence = allRows[z].FindElement(By.XPath("/td[@heading='colSequence']"));
```

Where `allRows[z]` is a row `IWebElement`.

I am just having a brain cramp with XPath in C#. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the complete code? And what you've tried?

Comment: Can you please post correct html snippet of your application?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Taking all the table rows in list collection.    
IList<IWebElement> tableTR = driver.FindElement(By.Id("TABLE_ID")).FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

    //Loop on rows
    foreach(IWebElement element in tableTR)
    {
    //for every row if the header tag equals what you need you do the code inside.
    if(element.GetAttribute("headers").Equals("colSequence")
    {
    //do your stuff...
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, describe the origin of the problem in english and submit the changes.

Comment: The english version is that I do not understand XPath syntax in Selenium for C#. Given an IWebElement for a <tr>, how would I construct an XPath to find a <td> within it from the headers attribute. Thanks.

Comment: //tr[contains(.,'colSequence')]